# Azure Service Bus for messaging and saga persistence

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm trying to persist the states of my saga into the Session of the AzureService Bus Messages. As long as the State of the Sage is just in memory it works fine. But if I activate *RequiresSession* and use a *MessageSessionSagaRepository*, my sage isn't doing anything anymore.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host(ConnectionString);
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(EnrichQueue, e =>
        {                       
            // works
            //e.StateMachineSaga(new EnrichmentStateMachine(), new InMemorySagaRepository<EnrichmentState>());

            // doesn't work
            e.RequiresSession = true;
            e.StateMachineSaga(new EnrichmentStateMachine(), MessageSessionSagaRepository.Create<EnrichmentState>());

        });
    }));
});
```

Did I miss something that I should have configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is a bit mixed, I'd suggest cleaning it up to bring it up to date and make it consistent:

```csharp
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddSagaStateMachine<EnrichmentStateMachine, EnrichmentState>()
        .MessageSessionRepository();

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => 
    {
        cfg.Host(ConnectionString);

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(EnrichQueue, e =>
        {                       
            e.RequiresSession = true;

            e.ConfigureSaga<EnrichmentState>(context);
        });
    }));
});
```

Messages sent/published to that endpoint require a SessionId, which is [covered in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/servicebus.html#sessionid).